# Removing an unwanted directory folder from netbeans and fixing a "is already under version control"

Tags: java, netbeans

I have two issues i would like to get fixed, yet in my attempt to fix the issues i have managed to descend down to an angry primate screaming and shouting at my pc.

Here are my issues (some of which cannot be solved by an online community),
Earlier today i thought it would be a great idea to create a folder called "res", res would be used to store images and wav files for a game i am making. Now, if the wav file i am testing is not inside this folder and the directory to the wav file is right it works fine, it looks like this ".getResource(fileName);". But when i do have the wav file in the "res" folder, i changed the directory to the following .getResource("res/"+fileName); i get the following
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
1 warning
as well as a nullPointerException pointing to all the stuff relating to sound.

So after being incredibly frustrated, i removed "res" folder, then the project stopped compiling as it cannot find "res", so i recreated res folder, keeping the wav file out of it which worked just fine. I then felt happy about it and thought, ya i'm done for a while, lets commit this to SVN.
On attempt to commit my work i get a "is already under version control" error for the "res" folder

so to recap this

> i created a folder called "res" in my project folder (via netbeans)
>
> i put a wav file into "res" and found it threw errors
>
> i removed the wav file from "res" and it worked just fine
>
> i deleted res folder and project refused to compile without this very important folder
>
> i recreated res folder and then tried to commit my work to SVN and SVN doesn't want my children anymore.
>
> I am now left with children i cannot put somewhere safe and an unwanted ghost in my house (folder in my project folder that wont do anything)

assistance, as always is greatfully accepted and welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

With respect to the SVN problem:

NB tends to add or delete directories on SVN automatically (but not commit) and it might be confused after the delete/recreation.

I'd suggest using a different tool (SVN command line or TortoiseSVN, for example) to verify which operations does SVN are pending and try reverting operations on the `res` directory. If SVN marks `res` as existing then you might try veryfing that the directory is not already on the repository.

Also you might remove the SVN cache from your Netbeans directory (previously called `%HOME%\.netbeans\cache\svn` and now (NB 7.2) changed to `%HOME%\Netbeans\Cache\7.2\svncache`.

An extreme solution would be to make a new checkout and copy your changes from the old working copy to the new one.

Comment: thanks for the response. I somehow managed to get it working again. I now can commit my work to SVN again